# Passing Json as stream to WCF method

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have created a website using WCF REST Service Template 40(CS) and It has a service method like this:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "CTNotification", Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
          RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]      

public string CTNotification(Stream contents)
```

How can I pass json to it ? I can not make the service parameter as string because client will be sending json as stream. How can I make a post call using C# to this service method with content type = application/json

Regards,
Asif Hameed

Comment: If I understand, you want to get the JSON stream as JSON object inside your method?      You have to implement data contracts then.

Comment: yes json as stream of type application/json with above signature of the service method

Comment: Have a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/327420/WCF-REST-Service-with-JSON

Comment: @mtsiakiris : Thanks for the response. I checked the link but it does not post json to any method which has Stream parameter.

Comment: You have to createyour own web method that receives the data as string and manipulate it to create your object(s).
[WebMethod]
public string GetData(string JsonRequest){ .... }

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you are doing this Synchronously or sync, but here is how to pass your args. The implementation may differ based on the needs of the client

```
    HttpWebRequest httpWReq =  (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ServiceAddress + "CTNotification/");

                //parameters
                byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);

                httpWReq.Method = "POST";
                httpWReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
                httpWReq.ContentLength = data.Length;
                httpWReq.Timeout = 1000;

                using (Stream newStream = httpWReq.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }
```